# What object-oriented GUI design would properly combine Command and Observer patterns?

Tags: java, design-patterns, command-pattern, observer-pattern

Is there an object-oriented GUI design that would be a reasonable combination of the Command and Observer patterns?

My Java GUI attempts to combine Command and Observer patterns as follows:

- the client is an observer of the Command receiver (e.g. an input GUI screen, or a dialog)
- the invoker is an instance variable of the client
- the update() method of the client receives the Command receiver's input and updates the invoker with the appropriate Command

What is making me uncomfortable with this implementation is that the update() method comprises a huge number of conditional if statements.

e.g.

```
public class Client implements Observer {
    InputScreen inputScreen;
    Invoker director;
    InputScreenCommand inputScreenCommand;

    public Client {
        inputScreen = new InputScreen();
        inputScreen.registerObserver(this);            
        inputScreenCommand = new InputScreenCommand(inputScreen)
        director.setCommand(inputScreenCommand);
        director.invoke();
    }

    public void update(String command) {
        if (command.equals("Input Screen 2")) {
            inputScreen.removeObserver(this);
            // generate new receiver/subject
            inputScreen2.registerObserver(this);
            // generate new Command
            director.setCommand(inputScreen2Command);
            director.invoke();
        }
        // and so on through all the permutations of input from receivers
    }
}
```

The proper way of using the Command pattern to effectively and efficiently handle GUI events is eluding me at the moment. Is the Observer pattern a useful partner for it?

Comment: I don't get what you want in the end. Patterns must solve problems, not be used for the sake of being used. So what's the problem you are solving?

Comment: @Andrey: the problem I am trying to solve is setting up an efficient and effective object oriented GUI design that is extensible to multiple applications that I have planned. I apologise for your confusion. If the question is subjective or offensive please feel free to nominate it for deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the overall design solution for UI would be MVC, or some of it's variations (actually, people usually leave out an explicit controller, and have a model and a view which is basically coupled with controller). Commands are not essential there, unless you want to establish an undo framework.

In any case, if you use Java, you are likely to be stuck with a UI library (like Swing or SWT), and this library will impose a great deal of your design.

Comment: Thanks! I have used MVC before. I will give it a fair shake again since you recommend it. The Command pattern looked ideal for my application because of undo and macros but I guess it's beyond my powers to implement it at this point in time using the Observer pattern in an efficient and effective manner.